# Multiple inputs on same line

Tags: c, arrays, input, line

I want to ask for the student number and marks on the same line.

The user inputs the student number. If it is valid then it should move a couple spaces to the right and allow the user to input a mark.

At present it is going to the next line to input my mark.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    int counter;
    int marks[40];
    float num_grades = 0;
    int row = 1;
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    float pass_average = 0;
    float fail_average = 0;
    int array_pos = 0;
    int fail = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    float pass_sum = 0;
    float fail_sum = 0;
    float biggest = 0;
    float smallest = 0;

    //int grade[40];
    int student_num[40];

    printf("       ---=== IPC mark Analyser V2.0 ===---\n");

    printf("Please enter the number of students(between 3 and 40): ");
    scanf("%d", &counter);


    while (counter > 40 || counter < 3)
    {
        printf("Invalid number, enter a number between 3 and 40 inclusive: ");
        scanf("%d", &counter);

    }

    printf("Row   Std No Mrk\n");
    printf("--- --------- ---\n");

    num_grades = counter;
    while (counter > 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", row);
        printf("___________ ___\r%3d ", row);
        scanf("%d", &student_num[array_pos]);


        while (student_num[array_pos] < 10000000 || student_num[array_pos] >      999999999)
        {
            printf("Error: Enter student number values between 10000000 and 999999999 inclusive.\n");
            printf("%d ", row);
            printf("___________ ___\r%3d ", row);

            scanf("%d", &student_num[array_pos]);
        }


        scanf("%d", &marks[array_pos]);
        //printf("\r%3d %09d ___ ", row, student_num[array_pos]);
        //scanf("%d", &marks[array_pos]);

        while (marks[array_pos] < 0 || marks[array_pos] > 100)
        {
            printf("Error: Enter mark values between 0 and 100 inclusive.\n");
            printf("\r%3d %09d ___ ", row, student_num[array_pos]);
            scanf("%d", &marks[array_pos]);
        }

        if (num_grades == counter)
        {
            smallest = marks[array_pos];
            biggest = marks[array_pos];
        }
        if (marks[array_pos] >= 50)
        {
            pass++;
            pass_sum += marks[array_pos];
        }
        else if (marks[array_pos] < 50)
        {
            fail++;
            fail_sum += marks[array_pos];

        }
        if (marks[array_pos] > biggest)
        {
            biggest = marks[array_pos];
        }
        if (marks[array_pos] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = marks[array_pos];
        }

        row++;
        counter--;
        sum += marks[array_pos];
        array_pos++;
    }


    printf("=================\n");
    printf("Marks Entered, printing results:\n");
    printf("Row   Std No Mrk\n");
    printf("--- --------- ---\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
    {
        printf("%03d %09d %3d ", i + 1, student_num[i], marks[i]);
        if (marks[i] == biggest) {
            printf("***Highest Mark***");
        }
        if (marks[i] == smallest) {
            printf("***Lowest Mark***");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    average = sum / num_grades;
    pass_average = pass_sum / pass;
    fail_average = fail_sum / fail;

    printf("===================\n");
    printf("Total of %d students passed with an average of %.1f.\n", pass, pass_average);
    printf("Total of %d students failed with an average of %.1f.\n", fail, fail_average);
    printf("Highest mark in group: %.0f\n", biggest);
    printf("Lowest mark in group: %.0f\n", smallest);
    printf("The average of all marks in this group is %.1f.\n", average);
    printf("Program Ended.\n");

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here for a question asking how to input two numbers on the same line. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. There is no need to post the whole app, but perhaps it is because you request two inputs separately, and the `newline` after the first moves - to a new line. The whole thing seems ridiculously turgid. Why don't you get both data items in the same input with, say `int entries = scanf("%d%d", &stud, &mark);` and then analyse what was input? Apart from that you could try`ncurses`.

Comment: You are trying to do to much with scanf and printf. It would be better if you just asked line by line for each input, then printed a table at the end. Otherwise you need to look up a cursor library on your system about how to move the cursor, clear lines, turn off echoing, etc.